# How to find an element inside a Node

Tags: go, goquery

I am trying to get data with [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#api) from an HTML document. The HTML is structured like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-holder body">
    <div class="simple-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="simple-mask">
      <table>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-holder body">
    <div class="simple-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="simple-mask">
      <table>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to get is the content of tbody of the first Node object. I am getting the first Node like this:

```
container := doc.Find(".container")
tableHolder := container.Find(".table-holder.body").Nodes[0]
```

But, since there is no `Find` method on the `Node` struct, I am wondering how can I then get the `tbody` from the Node struct?

Comment: There's a `Find` on the `Selection` returned by `Find`. Did you try storing the result of `Find` (rather then just grabbing its first Node) and then using that to "dig deeper"?

Comment: Not sure how I can use Find in this case when both Nodes have same classes, I need to dig deeper specifically in the first Node

Comment: Admittedly I've never used goquery and it's been ages since I've use jquery so I may very well be wrong, but I assumed that the selection will hold a set of *all* nodes that matched the query, and subsequent calls to Find on a selection would query the whole set of that selection, returning child nodes of all the nodes from the receiver selection, while preserving the order in which they exist in the html... If this is the case you should be able to then grab the `tbody` just as you've grabbed the `table-holder`...

Comment: ... i.e. `container.Find(".table-holder.body").Find("tbody").Nodes[0]` should work, no?

Comment: That said, if you want to be more explicit you probably could use [`First`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.First)? i.e. `container.Find(".table-holder.body").First().Find("tbody").Nodes[0]`?

Comment: I actually had to this to get the rows:  ```doc.Find(".container").Find(".table-holder.body").First().Find("tbody").Find("tr")```

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/c7VFxxBN6ue